# Deploying Struts 2 project in JBOSS 7

Tags: java, spring, struts2, nullpointerexception, jboss7.x

I am facing problem while deploying my web application in Jboss 7.1.1 final.
while deploying it gives me many warnings like below:

```
12:41:29,961 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-6) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 132 ms
12:41:30,169 WARN  [com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.FileManager] (MSC service thread 1-6) Could not create JarEntryRevision for [vfs:/content/Gurukul.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.2.1.1]!: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:131) [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:150) [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:114) [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.FileManager$JarEntryRevision.build(FileManager.java:307) [xwork-core-2.2.1.1.jar:2.2.1.1]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.FileManager.loadFile(FileManager.java:145) [xwork-core-2.2.1.1.jar:2.2.1.1]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.FileManager.loadFile(FileManager.java:105) [xwork-core-2.2.1.1.jar:2.2.1.1]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:898) [xwork-core-2.2.1.1.jar:2.2.1.1]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadDocuments(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:154) [xwork-core-2.2.1.1.jar:2.2.1.1]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.init(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:121) [xwork-core-2.2.1.1.jar:2.2.1.1]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:179) [xwork-core-2.2.1.1.jar:2.2.1.1]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66) [xwork-core-2.2.1.1.jar:2.2.1.1]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:371) [struts2-core-2.2.1.1.jar:2.2.1.1]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:415) [struts2-core-2.2.1.1.jar:2.2.1.1]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69) [struts2-core-2.2.1.1.jar:2.2.1.1]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51) [struts2-core-2.2.1.1.jar:2.2.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:447) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3269) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3865) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
```

But ultimately the war was deployed and I was able to open the url in Jboss 7.1.1 final. but when I am trying to login to the application it gives me following error.

**Console Output:**

```
12:42:08,199 INFO  [com.ericsson.tni.action.AuthorizationAction]  Entered login
12:42:08,201 INFO  [com.ericsson.tni.action.AuthorizationAction]  Authentication Started For User : etapguh
12:42:08,201 INFO  [com.ericsson.tni.action.AuthorizationAction]  Authentication Result : success
12:42:08,202 INFO  [com.ericsson.tni.action.AuthorizationAction]  Initiating authorisation : 
12:42:08,202 ERROR [stderr]  java.lang.NullPointerException
12:42:08,203 ERROR [stderr]     at com.ericsson.tni.action.AuthorizationAction.login(AuthorizationAction.java:92)
12:42:08,203 ERROR [stderr]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
12:42:08,203 ERROR [stderr]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
12:42:08,204 ERROR [stderr]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
12:42:08,204 ERROR [stderr]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
12:42:08,204 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:452)
12:42:08,205 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:291)
12:42:08,205 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:254)
12:42:08,205 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
12:42:08,206 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
12:42:08,206 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
12:42:08,206 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
12:42:08,207 ERROR [stderr]     at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
12:42:08,207 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
12:42:08,208 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
12:42:08,208 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:133)
12:42:08,208 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
12:42:08,209 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
12:42:08,209 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
12:42:08,209 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
12:42:08,210 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
12:42:08,210 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
12:42:08,210 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
12:42:08,211 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
12:42:08,211 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
12:42:08,212 ERROR [stderr]     at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
12:42:08,212 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
12:42:08,212 ERROR [stderr]     at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
12:42:08,213 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
12:42:08,213 ERROR [stderr]     at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
12:42:08,213 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
12:42:08,214 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
12:42:08,214 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
12:42:08,215 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
12:42:08,215 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
12:42:08,216 ERROR [stderr]     at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
12:42:08,216 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
12:42:08,217 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:142)
12:42:08,217 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
12:42:08,218 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:166)
12:42:08,218 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
12:42:08,219 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
12:42:08,219 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
12:42:08,219 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
12:42:08,219 ERROR [stderr]     at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
12:42:08,220 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
12:42:08,220 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:190)
12:42:08,220 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
12:42:08,221 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
12:42:08,221 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
12:42:08,222 ERROR [stderr]     at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
12:42:08,222 ERROR [stderr]     at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:485)
12:42:08,222 ERROR [stderr]     at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
12:42:08,222 ERROR [stderr]     at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
12:42:08,223 ERROR [stderr]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
12:42:08,223 ERROR [stderr]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
12:42:08,224 ERROR [stderr]     at com.ericsson.tni.web.interceptor.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:47)
12:42:08,224 ERROR [stderr]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
12:42:08,224 ERROR [stderr]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
12:42:08,224 ERROR [stderr]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
12:42:08,225 ERROR [stderr]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
12:42:08,225 ERROR [stderr]     at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
12:42:08,225 ERROR [stderr]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
12:42:08,226 ERROR [stderr]     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
12:42:08,226 ERROR [stderr]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
12:42:08,226 ERROR [stderr]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
12:42:08,227 ERROR [stderr]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
12:42:08,227 ERROR [stderr]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
12:42:08,227 ERROR [stderr]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
12:42:08,227 ERROR [stderr]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
12:42:08,228 ERROR [com.ericsson.tni.action.AuthorizationAction]  null
```

The same projects runs very fine in Tomcat 7.

**Code Snippet:**

```
@Action(TNIBeans.AUTHORIZATION_ACTION)
@Scope(TNIBeans.BEAN_SCOPE)
public class AuthorizationAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware,ServletRequestAware {

    private InputStream inputStream;
    /**
     * Logger for this class
     */
    private static final Logger logger = Logger
            .getLogger(AuthorizationAction.class);
    @Autowired
    private XStream xstream;
    
    public void logException(String message) {
        logger.error(message);
    }

    public void log(String msg) {
        logger.info(msg);
    }
    
    HttpServletRequest request = null;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(TNIBeans.EMPLOYEE_SERVICE_IMPL)
    private EmployeeService employeeServiceImpl;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(TNIBeans.CODE_SERVICE_IMPL)
    private CodeMasterService codeMasterService;
    
    Map<String,Map<String,String>> codeMaster = null;
    private String strResult = null;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8517227229292215672L;

    private Map<String, Object> session = null;
    private Employee emp = null;
    
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String roles;
    private String responseMsg;

    public String login () throws Exception {
        log("Entered login");
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("execute() - start.....");
        }
        try {
            log("Authentication Started For User : "+userName);
        //  employeeServiceImpl.authenticate(userName, password);
            inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream("success".getBytes("UTF-8"));
            log("Authentication Result : success");
            log("Initiating authorisation : ");  // This is printed in Console output if u observe (ie, till here the code                                  executed properly)

    // It couldn't create instance of "employeeServiceImpl" interface defined above..... 

            emp = employeeServiceImpl.authorize(userName);
```

**Another code snippet of authorize function:**

```
@Override
    public Employee authorize(String signum) throws BusinessException {
        System.out.println("Hi Tapo..."+signum); // this is not printed in console output if u observe (ie, controller doesn't                                  enter authorize function) 
        logger.info("authorize : "+signum);
        Employee emp = null;
        try{
            emp = findRoles(signum);
            if (WebConstants.adminSignum.equalsIgnoreCase(signum)) {
                emp.setSignum(signum);
                emp.setName("System Administrator");
                emp.setRoles(Role.LnCD_ADMIN);
                emp.setRoles(Role.LnCD_DELEGATE);
                emp.setRoles(Role.SYS_ADMIN);
            }
            return emp;
        }catch(BusinessException e){
            throw new BusinessException(e.getMessage());
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new BusinessException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably you don't have enough libraries in configuration.

Comment: Hi Roman,Thanks for your reply. It's a maven supported project and it has all the required libraries in it's war file. Moreover it is running perfectly fine in Tomcat 7. can you tell me what jar file I am missing?

Comment: did you use tomcat runtime libraries in the project deps?

Comment: Sorry I am not getting your question.
While deploying the same project (which runs in Tomcat) into Jboss 7 I get warning like --
12:41:30,169 WARN  [com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.FileManager] (MSC service thread 1-6) Could not create JarEntryRevision for [vfs:/content/Gurukul.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.2.1.1]!: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
 .......
and while logging into application (in authorize method) I am getting the following error like -
  java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I am using xwork-core-2.2.1.1.jar in WEB-INF/lib directory.

I am new to JBoss and J2EE architecture, please help me out.
Tapo

Comment: Do you mean `employeeServiceImpl` is not wired?

Comment: The warning about xwork-core-2.2.1.1.jar you may remove from question, it is meaningless.

Comment: employeeServiceImpl is wired. if the warning is meaningless why it is giving me error-
ERROR [stderr]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
12:42:08,204 ERROR [stderr]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:452)

Comment: This is nothing, remove the warning, remove console log and post server.log here.

Answer (score 2):

Those warnings are only available during devMode(=true), if you don't use the Convention plugin, everything should be ok.

The proper support for JBoss 7 was added as from version 2.3.1 of Struts 2.

Answer (score 0):

According to your console output that is relevant to the jboss `server.log` file that is in your deployment folder you've got `java.lang.NullPointerException` in the method `login` of the `AuthorizationAction`. And the exception occured right in the statement

```
emp = employeeServiceImpl.authorize(userName);
```

That is `employeeServiceImpl` is `null`. If it's not `null` then we've seen `"Hi Tapo..."` in the logs. Nothing similar happened.

Then the `employeeServiceImpl` is a property that initialized via Spring application context. Even not you posted the `aplicationContext.xml` here I assume there's bean definition in it. Then it should be injected, again assume that this works too, as for you said that it's well running at Tomcat server.

Hence this could only happen if the bean creation failed. This is exactly the case where `NullPointerException` you shouldn't prevent.

For that moment we only know that `employeeService` bean failed. We don't have the sources. You didn't posted it. Then we required additional exceptions from the log file to find the cause why the bean is not created. Didn't get it too.

So, the only way to find out to deploy the working app in Tomcat 7 on JBoss 7. And what happened, is some integrated frameworks become behave slightly different as expected. And they became load additional libraries that is not used under Tomcat. This is because the features of JBoss that is not available in the Tomcat. Finally I found that my resources stopped loading because JBoss returns URLs with `vsf` protocol. Even my application understands `vsfzip` protocol I needed to add those protocol to make it working.